Getting error while trying to connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB in SQL Server
I've created a winforms app in Visual Studio 2022 and for it to work I've copied the .mdf file of my database (receipts) and pasted in the directory of the project, but when I'm trying to connect to SSMS using (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB I'm getting this error:

Cannot connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.
Additional information:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

When I connect using (local) it connects.
I've tried to uninstall SSMS and updated Visual Studio 2022, but it has not helped.

Have you looked in the Windows Event Log for further details, as suggested?

Why would you place the mdf file in the application's binaries directory? Why not leave the mdf file alone and connect to the database through your SQL Server (/Express) instance?

@MartinCostello I deleted localdb and created a new instance it is working now.

@gunr2171 I have a win forms app and it is using data base so I'm trying to make a setup so that it can installed on others pc without installing ssms in their systems...

(local) is the default, unnamed SQL Server instance - full installation. LocalDB is a special version of the SQL Server Express edition only - not the full install.

Also: it's the SQL Server engine/core that's at version 2022 - SSMS uses different numbering schemes (not year-based) and is at v20.0.1 as the most recent version right now

LocalDB is separate to SQL Server Express and can be installed on its own.

I already had a similar name instance with small letters so I deleted it and made (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB this one and it is working now!

The following "hack" sometimes does the job.
Step 1. Click the "Cancel" button in the "Connect to Server" box that shows up when you open up the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Step 2. Go to the Object Explorer box and click
"Connect" -> "Database Engine"
Step 3. The same "Connect to Server" box (from Step 1) will pop up, but this time, when you click "Connect" it works.
